# AWS ALB returns 411 after ELB classic switch over

Tags: http-post, aws-application-load-balancer, chunked-encoding, aws-elb, http-status-code-411

I have a new ALB that has requests logging as 411 or "Length Required" that were previously 200 OK when the requests went to an old ELB classic. The requests are on loop from the source in another VPC out of my control and haven't been changed. Access control and the security group rules are all identical. The following fields in the log are 411; elb_status_code, target_status_code and target_status_code_list.The POST body is empty so the request is essentially acting like a GET in that the full set of parameters, key and id, are used inline like the example below.
https://hostname.example.com/api/method/getdata?key=1234&id=16

How can I convince the ALB that the POST request is valid?